# Contracting Indices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Does anyone know how to get from (1) to (2) in the system

$$    \begin{align}
    \mathrm{g}^{\mu\nu}_{,\rho}+
    \mathrm{g}^{\sigma\nu}{{\Gamma}}^{\mu}_{\sigma\rho}+
    \mathrm{g}^{\mu\sigma}{{\Gamma}}^{\nu}_{\rho\sigma}
    -\frac{1}{2}(
    {{\Gamma}}^{\sigma}_{\rho\sigma}+{{\Gamma}}^{\sigma}_{\sigma\rho}
    )
    \mathrm{g}^{\mu\nu}
    &=0,
\tag1
  \\
    \mathrm{g}^{[\mu\nu]}_{,\nu}
    +\frac{1}{2}(
    {{\Gamma}}^{\rho}_{\rho\nu}-{{\Gamma}}^{\rho}_{\nu\rho}
    )
    \mathrm{g}^{(\mu\nu)}
    &=0,
\tag2
    \end{align}
$$

by contracting equation (1) once with respect to ($\mu,\rho$), then with respect to ($\nu,\rho$)?

Where $\Gamma$ is not symmetric with respect to the lower Indices.

My attempt so far to solve this problem is:
Well, when contracting with respect to μ and ρ I get:
$$
-\frac{1}{2} g^{\rho \nu } {\Gamma} _{a\rho}^{a}-\frac{1}{2} g^{\rho
   \nu} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{a}+g^{a\nu} \Gamma _{a\rho}^{\rho}+g^{\rho a} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{\nu}+g_{,\rho}^{\rho\nu}=0
$$
and when contracting with respect to nu and ρ I get:
$$
-\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \rho } \Gamma _{a\rho}^a-\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu
   \rho} \Gamma _{\rho a}^a+g_{}^{a\rho } \Gamma _{a\rho}^{\mu }+g^{\mu a} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{\rho
   }+g_{,\rho }^{\mu \rho }=0
$$
when subtracting these two equations I get:
$$
\frac{1}{2} g_{}^{\mu \rho } \Gamma _{a\rho }^a-\frac{1}{2} g_{}^{\rho
   \nu } \Gamma _{a\rho }^a+\frac{1}{2} g_{}^{\mu \rho } \Gamma
   _{\rho a}^a-\frac{1}{2} g_{}^{\rho \nu } \Gamma _{\rho
   a}^a+g_{}^{a\nu } \Gamma _{a\rho }^{\rho
   }-g_{}^{a\rho } \Gamma _{a\rho }^{\mu }-g_{}^{\mu a}
   \Gamma _{\rho a}^{\rho }+g_{}^{\rho a} \Gamma _{\rho
   a}^{\nu }-g_{,\rho }^{\mu \rho }+g_{,\rho }^{\rho \nu }=0
$$
I cant see how this is equal to equation (2)

Comment: I think this is a valid question for practising physicists. @OP: Explain a little more about what you tried. In general, we discourage people from cogging HW solutions off this phy.SE.

Comment: well, this is not a homework problem, but just an equation I found in Schrodinger's book "Space Time structure".

Comment: I tend to agree with Siva. Have a look at the symmetry properties of the different symbols when you substract the two contracted versions of equation (1).

Comment: Hi user38032. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Look, I already said that this isn't a homework.

Comment: These equations are in Schrodinger's Book "Space Time structure", page 110, and I just wanted to know how to get from (1) to (2), so If you don't know the answer stop leaving these useless comments about this being a homework problem.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the first prong of the homework-like question policy--that the question is sufficiently conceptual--but it looks to me that even if this question does pass that test, without some kind of attempt to show work yourself, this question will likely remain on hold and ultimately be closed.

Comment: The homework-like question policy is not applied because the questions was assigned as homework, but because that question's main value appears to be pedagogical (that is they are the kind of question that would be given to student because they teach a particular skill or point).

Comment: @Dmckee nice answers to such questions are extremely valuable for people who want to study the subject at a technical level. IMHO it is a valid technical question, and the closed loop of closed questions is not a good thing at all. One of them should be open and allowed to get a nice answer that certainly not only the people who upvoted the question would appreciate.

Comment: Note that (i) the two corresponding eqs. (12.14) and (12.15) in the book E. Schrodinger, _Space Time Structure,_ have asterisks on the $\Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\nu}$ symbols. This is defined in eq. (12.12). (ii) Moreover the metric tensors is typed in gothic, which refers to an implicit square root factor. (iii) And finally there is no symmetry assumed on the metric tensor and the $\Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\nu}$ symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attempt of obtaining

$$
g^{[\mu\nu]}_{,\nu}
    +\frac{1}{2}(
    {{\Gamma}}^{\rho}_{\rho\nu}-{{\Gamma}}^{\rho}_{\nu\rho}
    )
    g^{(\mu\nu)}
    =0,
$$
was almost right! The only thing missing was a little care with relabeling indices.
We will proceed in three main steps.

1.) So when contracting Eq. (1) with respect to $\mu$ and $\rho$, we get the identity:

$$
-\frac{1}{2} g^{\rho \nu } {\Gamma} _{a\rho}^{a}-\frac{1}{2} g^{\rho
   \nu} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{a}+g^{a\nu} \Gamma _{a\rho}^{\rho}+g^{\rho a} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{\nu}+g_{,\rho}^{\rho\nu}=0.
$$

Now by relabeling the dummy indices in the 3rd term as $ a \leftrightarrow \rho$, we get
that the 3rd term can be written as $g^{\rho \nu} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{a}$. Moreover, we 
can see that now the 2nd and 3rd term can be simplified: adding them together gives 
$+ \tfrac{1}{2}g^{\rho  \nu} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{a}$. By a final index label change $\nu \to \mu$, we get that:

$$
-\frac{1}{2} g^{\rho \mu } {\Gamma} _{a\rho}^{a}+\frac{1}{2} g^{\rho
   \mu} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{a}+g^{\rho a} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{\mu}+g_{,\rho}^{\rho\mu}=0. \; \; \; \; (A)
$$

2.) When contracting Eq. (1) with respect to $\nu$ and $\rho$, we get the identity:

$$
-\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \rho } \Gamma _{a\rho}^a-\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu
   \rho} \Gamma _{\rho a}^a+g_{}^{a\rho } \Gamma _{a\rho}^{\mu }+g^{\mu a} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{\rho
   }+g_{,\rho }^{\mu \rho }=0.
$$

Let us also rename the dummy indices in the 4th term as $ a \leftrightarrow \rho$. We can see now that the 4th term is simply $g^{\mu \rho } \Gamma _{a\rho}^a$, and the 1st and 4th term hence together give $\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \rho } \Gamma _{a\rho}^a$. Moreover, let us perform also the $ a \leftrightarrow \rho$ "dummy index relabeling", yielding $g_{}^{\rho a} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{\mu }$ for the 3rd term. After these manipulations our identity reads as

$$
\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \rho } \Gamma _{a\rho}^a-\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu
   \rho} \Gamma _{\rho a}^a+g_{}^{\rho a} \Gamma _{\rho a}^{\mu }+g_{,\rho }^{\mu \rho }=0. \; \; \; \; (B)
$$

3.) Now taking (B)-(A), we obtain:

$$
g_{,\rho }^{\mu \rho } -g_{,\rho}^{\rho\mu} + \frac{1}{2}\left( g^{\mu \rho }  +  g^{\mu \rho }\right) \left( \Gamma _{a\rho}^a - \Gamma _{\rho a}^a \right)=0,
$$
which after the $a \to \rho$ and $\rho \to \nu$ relabeling is exactly the same as the desired Eq. (2).

Comment: I don't get why you relabeled $\nu \to \mu$ in you first step.

Comment: You don't understand why I did it or why I am allowed to do it? I will answer both. 1) Why did I do it? I calculated (B) beforehand, and I saw that after this $\nu \to \mu$ relabeling I get an Eq. (A) which subtracted from (B) gives me the equation you wanted to obtain. Why am I allowed to do it? Without the $\nu \to \mu$ relabeling I would get $-\tfrac{1}{2} g^{\rho\nu}\Gamma_{a\rho}^{a}+\tfrac{1}{2} g^{\rho\nu} \Gamma_{\rho a}^{a}+g^{\rho a} \Gamma_{\rho a}^{\nu}+g_{,\rho}^{\rho\nu}=0$, which I guess also you agree with. Now $\nu$ can be any index, so I simply choose $\nu=\mu$.

Comment: I don't understand why you're allowed to do it. Are you saying that equation (2) is only valid if ν=μ?.

Comment: No! Eq.(2) is also valid when $\nu\ne\mu$, you have to keep track of all the relabelings that I did. Let's go slower. Forget about all the previous equations, and answer to this: 1) Do you agree that if $-\tfrac{1}{2} g^{\rho\nu}\Gamma_{a\rho}^{a}+\tfrac{1}{2} g^{\rho\nu}\Gamma_{\rho a}^{a}+g^{\rho a} \Gamma_{\rho a}^{\nu}+g_{,\rho}^{\rho\nu}=0$ holds for any $\nu\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, then also $-\tfrac{1}{2} g^{\rho\mu}\Gamma_{a\rho}^{a}+\tfrac{1}{2} g^{\rho\mu} \Gamma_{\rho a}^{a}+g^{\rho a} \Gamma_{\rho a}^{\mu}+g_{,\rho}^{\rho\mu}=0$ holds for any $\mu\in\{0,1,2,3\}$? It's the same set of Eqs.

Comment: @user38032 So think over my previous question. After you answered, we'll make the next step.

Comment: yes, I agree. for both equations.

Comment: It's great that you saw the previous point! Now we are almost there. So you agree that $-\frac{1}{2}g^{\rho\mu}\Gamma_{a\rho}^{a}+\frac{1}{2}g^{\rho\mu}\Gamma _{\rho a}^{a}+g^{\rho a}\Gamma_{\rho a}^{\mu}+g_{,\rho}^{\rho\mu}=0$ (holds for all $\mu \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. Then my next question: Do you also agree with my derivation in point (2) of my answer that $\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\rho}\Gamma_{a\rho}^{a}-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\rho}\Gamma _{\rho a}^{a}+g^{\rho a}\Gamma_{\rho a}^{\mu}+g_{,\rho}^{\mu\rho}=0$ holds for all $\mu \in \{0,1,2,3\}$? If yes, subtract the two equations, and give me the answer.