# Contracting Indices in General relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I was reading a book about general relativity and I came across these two equations

$$    \begin{align}
    \mathrm{g}^{\mu\nu}_{,\rho}+
    \mathrm{g}^{\sigma\nu}{\Gamma}^{\mu}_{\sigma\rho}+
    \mathrm{g}^{\mu\sigma}{\Gamma}^{\nu}_{\rho\sigma}
    -\frac{1}{2}(
    {\Gamma}^{\sigma}_{\sigma}+{{\Gamma}^{\sigma}_{\sigma\rho}}
    )
    \mathrm{g}^{\mu\nu}
    &=0,
\tag1
  \\
    \mathrm{g}^{[\mu\nu]}_{,\nu}
    +\frac{1}{2}(
    {\Gamma}^{\rho}_{\rho\nu}-{\Gamma}^{\rho}_{\nu\rho}
    )
    \mathrm{g}^{(\mu\nu)}
    &=0,
\tag2
    \end{align}
$$
Where the connection is not symmetric with respect to the lower Indices.

and it says that by contracting equation (1) once with respect to ($\mu,\rho$), then with respect to ($\nu,\rho$), then subtracting the resulting equations we can get equation (2), however I can't see how that's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94901/2451

Comment: This question is different from my last question because apparently the other sounded like a homework problem when its not. So I asked this new question.

Comment: You clearly didnt read the homework policy, did you? It doesnt matter whether a question is literally a homework assignment or not. It's the type of knowledge that you're after.

Comment: You can add the edits to the other upvoted question to improve it, there is no need of asking a new one. The first upvoted question has 3 reopen votes and if you copy the improvements from this one there, you might have a chance ... And please calm down. Btw when you click on my profile you can see that some people are working on setting up a new physics site ... ;-).